# Find all files with an extension and view them

Tags: linux

I want to find all files having a same extension and view content of those found files.
ex: Find all js files in /home/user/Desktop/test and view the content of that files in linux terminal .

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question... [How do I ask homework questions on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+ask+homework+questions+on+Stack+Overflow). You are expected to make an effort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

find . -name *.js -exec cat {} \; in test directory

Comment: may be safier to quote `"*.js"` in case there is js file in current folder, also final `\;` may be changed to `+` to optimize number of cat processes spawned

Answer (score -1):

If you only care about the contents of a single directory you can use the command `ls /home/user/Desktop/test *.js | cat`. If you need to recursively you can use the command `find /home/user/Desktop/test -name *.js | cat`

Comment: this wont work , this will only list the files , i tried this at the beginning , i have include the solution for the problem in the question

Comment: This seems far too complicated. `cat /home/user/Desktop/test/*.js` is sufficient. No need for `ls` and pipelines.